# How do I minify '@import' css files with wp-minify?

Tags: css, optimization

I am trying to use wp-minify to minify my js/css on the fly. I can get the 'direct' css files to be minified, but I can't seem to get wp-minify to minify the 'linked' css files. My theme is a child theme off of twenty-ten, so my child theme's styles.css gets minified, but not twenty-ten's styles file.

Comment: `@import` and parallel downloades don't work.

Comment: @kaiser If you make your comment the answer, I'll mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@import` prevents "parallel" downloads. I'd not suggest to use it in case you want to minify css files.

Answer (score 0):

[WP Minify](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-minify/) is not updated for long time.  Download WP Minify plugin and install using WordPress plugin installer.

After that go to [minify](https://code.google.com/p/minify/) page and download minify engine, unzip then copy 'min' folder to installed WP Minify's 'min' folder.

It has lot fixes and it takes care of `@import` files.